# Freeform Pro disrupting Channel Entries count variable

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, solspace-freeform

I have a `{exp:channel:entries}` loop inside of an `{exp:freeform:form}` pair tag. When I call the `{count}` variable inside the channel entries loop, I'm expecting the count of the channel entries. Instead, it is only returning `1`.

When I use this same exact channel entries loop outside the freeform tags, it correctly increments the count with each entry. I know that `{freeform:count}` exists and the I presume this is done in order to not interfere with the CE count.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the channel entries loop in an embedded template.

Comment: This worked. Do you mind providing me a technical explanation as to why?  Thanks!

Comment: @baph0mt Just a namespace collision. The embed is parsed completely separately, so there isn't any collision.